# Apache2::REST -- Creating a resource

Tags: perl, rest

I'm new to REST, I'm very new to Perl's Apache2::REST. I have 'Apache2::REST' installed and I'm reading from it's cookbook. 
I know 'REST' is working because when I go to http://localhost/api, I'm getting the proper response:

```
response message="" status="200">
<data api_mess="Hello, this is MyApp REST API"/>
</response>
```

Here is the code to MyAPP::REST::API

```
package MyApp::REST::API;
use warnings;
use strict;

use base qw/Apache2::REST::Handler/;

# Implement the GET HTTP method.
sub GET{
 my ($self, $request, $response) = @_;
 $response->data()->{'api_mess'} = "Hello, this is MyApp REST API";
 return Apache2::Const::HTTP_OK;
}

# Authorize the GET method.
sub isAuth{my ($self, $method, $req) = @_; return $method eq "GET";} 
1;
```

I'm ready to create a 'resource' so, I want to create a resource '/foo'.

The cookbook said to "Implement a Apache2::REST::Handler named MyApp::REST::API::foo"

I went to the perldoc documentation and I really couldn't understand it.

Can somebody shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

There is a demo installation included in the Apache2::REST module. When you configure your Apache2::REST mod_perl2 handler without any Apache2RESTHandlerRootClass setting (look in cpan documentation of the module or apache config), a demo installation is automatically installed at your API access point.

I looked in the files provided by the demo installation which gave me the hint in creating a resource.

For example:
For a resource called 'test' use this url http://localhost/test/. The files were located in (this is Debian) 
/usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Apache2/REST/Handler/test.pm.

For a resource called '/foo', I just made a copy of test.pm and called in foo.pm.

Please see https://code.google.com/p/apache2rest/wiki/DemoApplication